# How to get json value by string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I receive the following string from the server response：

```
var jsonData = '[{"firstName":"Bill","lastName":"Gates"},{"firstName":"George","lastName":"Bush"},{"firstName":"Thomas","lastName":"Carter"}]';
```

I see some jquery plugins can predefine the keys they want

like: index:"firstName", and they get a ul like

```
<li>Bill</li>
<li>George</li>
<li>Thomas</li>
```

If index:"lastName", they get a ul like

```
<li>Gates</li>
<li>Bush</li>
<li>Carter</li>
```

The only way I know how to parse a json format string is:

```
var object = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var firstName = object[i].firstName;
var lastName= object[i].lastName;
```

The plugin pass the index like a parameter

```
function f(index) {
    return object[i].index;
}
```

How can they achieve this？

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think this is some sort of internal mapping like `object[i]['index'] = 'Bill'` Therefore `object[i].index` will output `Bill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access object properties with square brackets. JS objects work like arrays in this regard.

```
var objects = JSON.parse(jsonData),
    key = "firstName";

objects.forEach(function (obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    // ...
});
```